# How disable cache of searches Microsoft SQL server or Dbeaver?

Tags: sql-server, database, caching

When I run a large query, it takes a while at first, but the next few times, it runs fast.
I wanted it to continue to take the same amount of time it did on the first run. Is there a way to disable this "cache"?

I looked in the settings but didn't find anything about.

Comment: If you are looking to test performance against a test database with no data preloaded in memory, then `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` is the command for you. (... for SQL Server that is. I do not know about Dbeaver.)

Comment: The question has nothing to do with dbeaver. it is just a client tool

Comment: The 'caching' isn't occurring on your tool, it's occurring on the database instance - usually SQL Server has cached the execution plan used for your query and will then re-use that plan; it doesn't need to decide how to perform the query, it just does what it did before. As @TN says, if you're doing this against a test database then DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS might help but *never* use that on a Production instance